# How can I reuse collections that would use the same backing iterator?

Tags: java, collections, iterator, guava

I'm fairly new to Java so my knowledge is pretty limited. I'm working on a personal project where I'm trying out some of the techniques used in Guava for creating views/transformations of collections. I made a class called View to take an inputted collection as the backing iterable, and a transformation, and then present it as a read-only iterable. (not a collection, though I don't think it makes much of a difference for this question). Here is a quick example of using it...

```
public class Node {
  public enum Change implements Function<Node, Coordinate> {
    TO_COORDINATE;
    @Override public Coordinate apply(Node node) {
      return new Coordinate(node);
    }
  }

  private HashSet<Node> neighborNodes = new HashSet<Node>();
  //various other members

  public View<Coordinate> viewNeighborCoordinates() {
    return new View<Coordinate>(neighborNodes, Change.TO_COORDINATE);
  }
}
```

now if some method wants to use viewNeighborCoordinates() of this node, and then later some other method also wants to viewNeighborCoordinates() of this node, it seems wasteful to always be returning new objects, right? I mean any number of things should be able to share reference to a view of the same backing iterable with the same transformation, since all they're doing is reading through it. Is there an established way of managing a shared pool of objects which can be "interned" like Strings are? Is it just having to make some sort of ViewFactory that stores a running list of views in use, and everytime someone wants a view, it checks to see if it already has that view and hands it out? (is that even more efficient)?

Comment: This is possible, but very unlikely to be helpful. Wrapping a view around an object is cheap (probably cheaper than finding an existing, equivalent view), and unless you're expecting tremendous numbers of identical views to be active simultaneously, it's not going to help with memory use.

Comment: Also, you're mixing up iterators and iterables.

Comment: sorry, changed it to backing iterable.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, interning is possible (look at [Interners](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interners.html)), but most probably a bad idea.

Another possibility is lazy initialization of a field storing the `View`. Since I'm lazy as well, I only point you to a Lombok implementation. Be careful with [DCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking), if you want to try this. In case your class is immutable, you may need no synchronization at all, like e.g. [String.hashCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode%28%29).

A very simple possibility is eager initialization of a field. Assuming you need the view often, it's the best way.

But without knowing more, your current implementation is best. Beware the [root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Don't optimize without profiling or benchmarking (and if you benchmark, then do it right, i.e., using [caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper) or [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh). Home-baked benchmarking in Java just doesn't work).